# Procedure or function 'sp_***' expects parameter '@', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to execute a stored procedure but getting following error:

> *Procedure or function 'SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS' expects parameter '@DESIGN_ID', which was not supplied.*

Below is my stored procedure.

I am trying to execute it in SQL need result in table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS
    @DESIGN_ID INT
AS
BEGIN 
   Delete From Design_Parameters where Design_ID = @DESIGN_ID
END

exec SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS
```

I know I am missing some very easy points. I would appreciate any help into this.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and VS2010 with VB.Net

Thanks :)

Comment: As a side-note: don't use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. That prefix has been reserved by Microsoft for their own use, and using it [causes performance degradation](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/) for your stored procedures!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your note. I will make a not of It.

Comment: Your parameter is required, why are you calling the procedure without a parameter? And where is the `GO` between the end of the procedure and the call? Also see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exec your stored procedure you need to pass it the @DESIGN_ID parameter it expects.

```
EXEC SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS 123
```

where 123 is the ID you want to pass to the stored procedure

Comment: Thanks for help. I have 1000 rows in Design_ID column and If I need to display entire data should I use : exec SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS @DESIGN_ID only? Please advise.

Comment: If you want to delete all 1000 records you would need to call your procedure 1000 times. As you've written it at the moment it will only delete 1 record at a time.

Answer (score 3):

```
exec SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS @DESIGN_ID = 5
exec SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS 5
```

Read up on [how to pass parameters to a stored procedure](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7132.asp).  You are asking for a parameter but not supplying it.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have 1000 rows in Design_ID column and If I need to display entire data should I use : exec SP_DELETE_DESIGN_PARAMETERS @DESIGN_ID only? Please advise.

Comment: @Joy1979 are you trying to "display entire data" or are you trying to delete data? Your procedure says one thing, but you are saying another.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Sorry about typing error. I meant by delete 1000 data. Thanks

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Sorry about spelling error. I am trying delete 1000 data. Thanks

Comment: @Joy1979 you need to update your question to better reflect your actual requirements. Also explain if you are trying to delete "1000 data" or if you are trying to empty the table and it just happens to have 1000 rows right now.